# Can one see the progress of an application in % for Spark using its REST API

Tags: linux, rest, apache-spark

I am running a Spark application on a Stand alone Spark cluster. If I check the status of the applications using the Spark REST API, I get something like the following.

```
curl localhost:4040/api/v1/applications

[ {
  "id" : "app-20191107150648-0000",
  "name" : "MyAppName",
  "attempts" : [ {
    "startTime" : "2019-11-07T14:06:47.372GMT",
    "endTime" : "1969-12-31T23:59:59.999GMT",
    "lastUpdated" : "2019-11-07T14:06:47.372GMT",
    "duration" : 0,
    "sparkUser" : "Username",
    "completed" : false,
    "appSparkVersion" : "2.4.4",
    "startTimeEpoch" : 1573135607372,
    "lastUpdatedEpoch" : 1573135607372,
    "endTimeEpoch" : -1
  } ]
}
```

My question is, is there any API which also shows how much the application has progressed in %. For example, if its half done, it shoud show 50%. I know its impossible to get an exact figure, but even an estimate would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a list of all stages for a given app from .../applications/[app_id]/stages, and then see how many have been finished via .../applications/[app_id]/stages?status=complete (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api). After making a daring assumption that all stages are created equal, you can divide the size of list #2 by #1, and get a percentage.